# How to configure a fencer for Namenode High avaialbility

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hadoop2

When I trying to format zookeeper the following error shows up:

```
 FATAL ha.ZKFailoverController: Fencing is not configured for NameNode at   
 impc2361/192.168.10.104:8020.

 You must configure a fencing method before using automatic failover.
 org.apache.hadoop.ha.BadFencingConfigurationException: 
 No fencer configured for NameNode at impc2361/192.168.10.104:8020
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the property `dfs.ha.fencing.methods` in `hdfs-site.xml`.

The `dfs.ha.fencing.methods` property is a list of scripts or Java classes which will be used to fence the active NameNode during a failover.

There are 2 methods for fencing, shell and ssh. Make sure the property is set with valid arguments.

Example:

```
<property>      
  <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
  <value>sshfence</value>
</property>
```

More details about valid values for this property can be found within official Hadoop documentation or [blog post(s)](https://cornerhadoop.blogspot.in/2017/01/fencing-method-for-zk-based-ha-in-hadoop.html).